# Angular it taking the old parameter when clicking button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I am trying to add a button which when clicked, calls a function which takes a parameter and sends it to my server. So far it looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="interview in $ctrl.pendingInterviews">
        <td>{{ interview.id }}</td>
        <td><a href="/#!/pending-interviews-list?interviewId={{interview.id}}"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" ng-click="$ctrl.addParticipant();"></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I have in my angular component:

```
var participant={
                    username:"mama",
                    interviewId:$routeParams.interviewId
                };
                console.log(participant);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(participant));

                this.addParticipant = function saveParticipant() {
                    console.log("in partikip")
                    Interview.addParticipant(JSON.stringify(participant))
                        .then(
                            function (errResponse) {
                                console.error('Error while fetching pending interviews');
                            }
                        );
                }
```

And what I have in my angular service:

```
function addParticipant(participant) {
                console.log("Im here too");
                console.log(participant + "asdasdsda");
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.post('http://localhost:8080/interviewsupdateparticipant', participant)
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        },
                        function (errResponse) {
                            console.error('Error while adding participant');
                            console.error(''+ participant.username +  participant.interviewId)
                            deferred.reject(errResponse);
                        }
                    );
                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

The problem is that first when I go to my page, participant from the controller has the username set to mama and the interviewId set to undefined. When I click the submit button, instead of sending the id and the hardcoded username, it sends undefined and the hardcoded username. Why? Why doesn't it automatically get the interviewId?

The moment I click Submit, the id stays undefined for some reason and it only changes if I click again. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things that could solve this:

- Try using [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref%20ngHref) instead of just href when you have variable part of your url
- Try passing the `interview.id` as a parameter to your `addParticipant()` method instead of getting it via the `$routeParams` variable
- You have an `input type="submit"` outside any form, and inside an `<a>` link, try changing that

Comment: Apparently, I've just tested and it always retains the last value, instead the one I click to add so in order to get what I want, I have to press SUbmit twice! :/ I don't know why

Comment: Maybe because you have an input inside a link, your method binded to the input is called BEFORE the redirection is done. Try removing the link, keeping the button, and passing your value as a parameter `ng-click="$ctrl.addParticipant(interview.id);"`and then, rerouting to the correct $route inside your controller

Comment: You were right! I did that and it works now! Thank you very much! Any idea why it would also throw Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0 ?

Comment: Seems like a typo in JSON. 
I advise you open a new discussion for this specific problem, but before, check the "network" tab of your browser devtools to see what json you send/receive